# Formula for finding 'near perfect' matches

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of +-8000 items which is the result after applying numerous techniques to remove duplicates (the list started at over 10000 items).

I now have the following issue -

Example
1. Jack Daniel
2. Jack Daniels
3. Jack Daniel's

Clearly all of the above relate to one item but they are still technically unique.  I tried pulling the first 4 letters and checking for matches however there were +-4000 and most of them were false positives i.e.

1. Jack Dxxx
2. Jack Bxxx

Both would pull Jack but would not be a valid duplicate.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Checking the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between each item and reporting the records with a small distance might be what you need to do.

Comment: @Zoredache how would you do that in Excel?

Comment: No idea.  I leave that to you to research.  Or possibly someone else who wants to spend the time writing up a full answer.

Comment: Excel does not have any built-in functionality to do this. You with  have to install an add-in (there are a few out there but are not free). Have a look at open refine which is free: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=B70J_H_zAWM, I had the same problem and it solved it for me (and it is very easy to transfer data from/to excel).

Answer (score 3):

Based on Zoredache's comment, here is [my sample workbook](http://ge.tt/8xSEMxw/v/0) using VBA and the *Levenshtein Distance* to find similar strings within a big list. 
It's based on @smirkingman and @Apostolos55 [answers on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243036/levenshtein-distance-in-excel).

> The Levenshtein distance between two words is the minimum number of single-character edits (insertion, deletion, substitution) required to change one word into the other

I implemented two different versions. Please check which function is faster for your case with 8000 values. If you're curious, view the full VBA [code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/87a6a9dc4f8843222bac) on [Github](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b442cad4051e9e7d357d). Raise the threshold in the line `const treshold = 1` if you want results with more than 1 required edit to get a match somewhere.

[image]

- Formula syntax: `=LevenshteinCompare( <cell_to_check> , <range_to_search_in> )`
  Example: `=LevenshteinCompare(A2;A$2:A$12)` (Notice the fixed range)
- Output syntax: `<number_of_required_edits> - [<match_address>] <match_value>`

---

```
Private Function Levenshtein(S1 As String, S2 As String)

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim l1 As Integer, l2 As Integer
Dim d() As Integer
Dim min1 As Integer, min2 As Integer

l1 = Len(S1)
l2 = Len(S2)
ReDim d(l1, l2)
For i = 0 To l1
    d(i, 0) = i
Next
For j = 0 To l2
    d(0, j) = j
Next
For i = 1 To l1
    For j = 1 To l2
        If Mid(S1, i, 1) = Mid(S2, j, 1) Then
            d(i, j) = d(i - 1, j - 1)
        Else
            min1 = d(i - 1, j) + 1
            min2 = d(i, j - 1) + 1
            If min2 < min1 Then
                min1 = min2
            End If
            min2 = d(i - 1, j - 1) + 1
            If min2 < min1 Then
                min1 = min2
            End If
            d(i, j) = min1
        End If
    Next
Next
Levenshtein = d(l1, l2)
End Function


Public Function LevenshteinCompare(S1 As Range, wordrange As Range)

Const treshold = 1
For Each S2 In Application.Intersect(wordrange, wordrange.Parent.UsedRange)
    oldRes = newRes
    newRes = Levenshtein(S1.Value, S2.Value)
    If oldRes < newRes And oldRes <> "" Or S1.Address = S2.Address Then
        newRes = oldRes
        newS2row = oldS2row
    Else
        oldS2 = S2
        oldS2row = S2.Address(0, 0)
    End If
    newS2 = oldS2
Next

If newRes <= treshold Then
    LevenshteinCompare = newRes & " - [" & newS2row & "]  " & newS2
Else
    LevenshteinCompare = ""
End If
End Function
```

That was fun ☜(ﾟヮﾟ☜)

Comment: Nice answer! I can see myself using this one. It might be better for this case to have a function which just returns the number of cells which are N edits or less away (analogous to `COUNTIF`). That would make the duplicate-removing process easier (because you could sort/filter by the second column).

Comment: @benshepherd `number of cells which are N edits or less away`. Can you explain what you mean by *number of cells*, the address, the total amount? If you change line `LevenshteinCompare = newRes & " - [" & newS2row & "]  " & newS2` to `LevenshteinCompare = newRes` you will only see the minimum amount of edits needed to match any other cell

Comment: What I meant was, rather than returning the min number of edits over the whole range, it would be useful to have a function which counted the number of cells in the range that were 1 edit or less away. (Also, since you're usually looking for the minimal number, can you break out of your compare function early, thus making it faster?)

Answer (score 0):

Use =len and if the difference is say less then 2 mark it as possible

and something like =mid(Value,(len_Value - 7),4) mark it as possilbe dupe.

Combined with what you already have you should get a much more doable set to work with.

**Edit**

Formulas like this, Notice that "Jack Daniel" <> "Jack Berries" in G2. but looks like a possible match everywhere else.  You would need to modify a bit to meet your specific needs but it should get to a manageable number.

C1   =IF(LEFT(A1,4)=LEFT(B1,4),"T","F")

D1   =IF(LEN(A1) - LEN(B1) <= 2, "T", "F")

E1   =LEN(A1)

F1   =LEN(B1)

G1   =IF(MID(A1,(E1 - 7),4) = MID(B1,(E1 - 7),4), "T","F")

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply James - Im not sure how to use the formula "=mid(Value,(len_Value - 7),4)"  I assume value is cell with the list and len_value is the result of =len?