# Use Excel to calculate similarity between two strings

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison

Is there any way to calculate the % difference between two strings in Excel? For example, oftentimes a customer sends us a list of items that they want us to match with items in our system based on description and item SKU #. However, matching by SKU does not always return an accurate result, especially if it is short and not unique. If there was a more efficient way of doing this than manually searching & matching, it would greatly increase the efficiency of my job.

Optimally, the function would return a number... higher the number, better the possibility of a match. To be clear, both comparison cells are defined, and both exist in the same row. This would not be a [Fuzzy Lookup](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011) (already have that add-in).

Possible?

Comment: Given that the customer may not use precisely the same terms, capitalization, word order, etc., can you describe how this is different from fuzzy logic?  It seems like you would need to create "dictionaries" and search for variations of multiple terms.

Comment: It is fuzzy logic, but fuzzy lookup is not the solution unless I'm unaware of how to use it properly.

Comment: @FurryWombat - there are a few tricks and limitations to it, but it can be a very useful tool. What's your issue with it?

Comment: How would you like to calculate the % difference between two strings?

Comment: @MikeHoney I've been using Fuzzy Lookup like a vlookup, less than perfect match, but more perfect than Excel defines by default... is there a way to use Fuzzy Lookup to calculate the difference between two specifically defined strings, rather than two columns? My intent is to perform the calculation, then sort the rows by greatest to least similarity, in an effort to support the the act of eyeballing 400-500 records at a shot.

Comment: Also see [Formula for finding 'near perfect' matches](http://superuser.com/q/668452/76571)

Comment: Different, because that post covers a lookup query. This covers comparison between two predefined strings.

Comment: @FurryWombat AFAIK Fuzzy Lookup only works on columns.  I would add a new column using a formula for your "specifically defined strings".

Comment: @Excell, just so everyone is perfectly clear, this is NOT a duplicate. And still, nobody has answered or even touched on a real solution to the actual question: comparing two defined strings for % of similarity. NOT looking for a fuzzy match to an entry inside a SET of data.

Comment: Look at the VBA solution from soandos on the linked duplicate. You can use the custom function to get exactly what you want. For example, to compare strings in A1 and B1, you would use the following formula: `=1-LEVENSHTEIN(A1,B1)/MAX(LEN(A1),LEN(B1))`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Fuzzy Lookup only works on columns. I would add a new column using a formula for your "specifically defined strings".

Comment: Answers should be definitive solutions to the problem.  Helpful hints should be comments, which this already was.  This really isn't answer material.  Please consider deleting it.  I won't downvote, but there are trigger-happy downvoters who might, and that would eat into your rep.